# How to Over/Under Sample data with multiple target variable(Multi-Output)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, classification, sampling, smote

Suppose I have a dataset with 2 Independent features and 6 dependent features as follows where `AA and BB` are independent and `A,B,C,D,E,F` are dependent variables.

```
AA        BB       A B C D E F
teacher   No       1 0 0 1 0 0
student   Yes      1 1 0 1 0 0
officer   Yes      0 0 1 0 0 0
engineer  Maybe    1 1 1 0 0 0
student   Sure     0 1 1 0 0 1
lawyer    Maybe    1 1 0 0 1 0
student   Yes      1 0 0 1 1 0
teacher   No       1 1 1 0 0 0
doctor    No       0 1 1 0 0 0
engineer  Maybe    1 0 0 1 1 0
```

If suppose I want to balance my data by means of upsampling or downsampling or oversampling, How may I do it? Normal SMOTE and sklearn techniques dont take multiple targets and throw alot of errors. Can someone please help me with this.

Comment: it is quite a bit easier to just weight classes, with the same result

Comment: what classifier/framework do you use?

Comment: I used MultiOutputClassifier with SGDClassifier, no tuning normal classifier, i am not able to improve the accuracy because the classes are imbalanced.

Comment: are you trying to just "balance" classes or do you have a specific target to hit?

Comment: btw, it will improve accuracy only if sampling/weighting of classes is close to that in the test dataset

Comment: To balance classes, just add `class_weight='balanced' to parameters of `SGDClassifier`

Comment: can you show me without using class_weight="balanced" , like by using some sampling techniques like smote if u can? @Marat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** resampling classes / weighted loss function will only improve your results if it makes the training set closer to the distribution of classes in the test set. Weighted loss function is preferred in this case.

How to resample the dataset:

```
class_counts = df['AA'].value_counts()
class_weights = len(class_counts)/class_counts
resampled_df = df.sample(
    n=class_counts.max()*len(class_counts),
    weights=df['AA'].map(class_weights), 
    replace=True)
```

Comment: The last target column does not get improve it gets all zero in given case and also the limitation here is that if the independent column is a text column then it gives the same result as before. @Marat

Comment: @AniketRele You can do this kind of resampling for any column, not just class. I am not sure what is your concern about the text column